# How can use one script for many id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have this code and i need use many id's and not only one like map1 but map1, map2, map3 and more.. For example ( $usamap = $('#map_id'); ) How can do this?

```
$usamap = $('#map1');
    function bindlinks() {
        $('*').unbind();
        $("#unbind_link").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $usamap.mapster("unbind");
            $usamap.width(720);
            bindlinks();
        });
        $("#rebind_link").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $usamap.mapster(default_options);
        });

        $("#unbind_link_preserve").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $usamap.mapster("unbind", true);
            bindlinks();
        });
        $("#tooltip").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var state = !$usamap.mapster('get_options').showToolTip;
            $('#tooltip_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
            $usamap.mapster("set_options", { showToolTip: state });
        });
        $("#single_select").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var state = !$usamap.mapster('get_options').singleSelect;
            $('#single_select_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
            $usamap.mapster("set_options", { singleSelect: state });
        });
        $("#is_deselectable").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var state = !$usamap.mapster('get_options').isDeselectable;
            $('#is_deselectable_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
            $usamap.mapster("set_options", { isDeselectable: state });
        });
```

Comment: Pass in the selector to a method.

Comment: I dont now how, you can show me an example

Comment: Use class names instead.

Comment: Diodeus sorry but i dont now how. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the map object into your `bindlinks`. The assumption I'm making is that you have multiple maps but a single control, and you want to make the controls apply to a different map every time.

```
function bindlinks(map) {
    // This is really bad..., affecting all links on the page
    // You should only unbind handlers you bound      
    $('*').unbind();

    $("#unbind_link").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        map.mapster("unbind");
        map.width(720);
        bindlinks();
    });
    $("#rebind_link").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        map.mapster(default_options);
    });

    $("#unbind_link_preserve").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        map.mapster("unbind", true);
        bindlinks();
    });
    $("#tooltip").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var state = !map.mapster('get_options').showToolTip;
        $('#tooltip_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
        map.mapster("set_options", { showToolTip: state });
    });
    $("#single_select").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var state = !map.mapster('get_options').singleSelect;
        $('#single_select_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
        map.mapster("set_options", { singleSelect: state });
    });
    $("#is_deselectable").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var state = !map.mapster('get_options').isDeselectable;
        $('#is_deselectable_state').text(state ? "enabled" : "disabled");
        map.mapster("set_options", { isDeselectable: state });
    });
}

// Call it like
bindlinks( $('#map_id') );

// And later 
bindlinks( $('#map_other_id') )
```